# How to decode qr code from SD card

Tags: java, android, zxing

I want to decode qr code from image on my sd card, and I don't want to use external scanner. I use Zxing library. I have some code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.qr);

    Bitmap bt = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/cameraApplicationSe/qr.png");

    img.setImageBitmap(bt);
    int [] pix = new int[bt.getWidth() * bt.getHeight()];
    LuminanceSource qr=new RGBLuminanceSource(bt.getWidth(),bt.getHeight(),pix);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(qr));

    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();        
    Result result;          
    try {
        result = reader.decode(bitmap);
        txt.setText(result.getText());
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        txt.setText("NotFoundException");
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

in Manifest file add user permission on Read and write external storage. in all attempt i receive in TextView -  NotFoundException. In image I have QR code, independently created. in website.
Where i have mistake? Please, help me.

Comment: have you tried to check values with debugger?

Comment: In ImageView displayed my image with qr code. in next steps, I don't know where looking for values

Comment: Is `R.drawable.qr` and `/cameraApplicationSe/qr.png` the same?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'm think - bitmap is empty, because many parameters have null and 0.

Comment: So I would start with checking is the value of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/cameraApplicationSe/qr.png"` points to the correct location

Comment: `R.drawable.qr` is pointing to the folder inside the apk. It's not the same as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/cameraApplication‌​Se/qr.png"`

Comment: Yes, path is correct, because have  image displayed in ImageView. Now I corrected my code, now image i get from camera and rewrite code on `LuminanceSource qr = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data,size.width,size.width,0,0,300,300,false);` . And he start decode qr code